# How to get the svg element from inside an embed tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

```
<embed id='mysvg' src='mysvg.svg' onload='myFunc(this)'/>
```

This loads an external svg file. Now inside myFunc I'd like to get a reference to the actual svg tag. Meaning, there's an `<svg>` inside this file, and I'd like to set an attribute on this svg tag from javascript. But how do I get a reference to it?

I tried:

```
function myFunc(elem)
{
    $(elem).find('svg').attr('preserveAspectRatio','none'); // doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps...

```
var svg = $(elem.getSVGDocument().documentElement);

svg.attr('preserveAspectRatio','none');
```

[documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) returns the root element of a document so you don't need to 'find' it.

Comment: wont it throw a cross-origin frame DOM exception